# IP アドレスの変更後、別セグメント間で通信は可能か？

Tags: network

画像のようにFile serverのIPアドレスを192.168.1.100/24 → 172.30.1.100/24に変更した場合、File serverから正常にファイルを取得できるのはPC①～④のどれでしょうか？
個人的にはすべて通信不可と判断しています。

HUBに接続している①、②はデータをすべてリピートするので通信できるのでは？という意見も聞きました。
③も同一MACアドレステーブルに属するのでFile serverと通信可能でしょうか？

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: 次の三つについて教えてください。1.IPアドレスを変更する前は全てのPCから取得可能だったのでしょうか？2.それぞれのPCもIPアドレスを変更しても良いのでしょうか？3.File serverでファイアウォールなどの機能により特定のIPアドレスからのみのアクセス以外は拒否すると言った制限をしているでしょうか？

Comment: 1.全て取得可能でした。(L2,L3SWでVLANが全て正しく設定されてpingが通る状態）2.PCのIPアドレスは変更不可です。3.FWの設定はありません。すべて許可です。

Comment: File serverを別セグメントで管理したいんだけど、どうしたらいいって感じの要件です。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

File serverのIPアドレスのみ変更し、それ以外は一切変更してはいけないというのであれば、次のようになります。(IPv6は無効という前提としてます)

- TCP/IPのユニキャストを使用するようなプロトコル(CIFSやNFSやFTPやSCP等)では、いずれのPCからも取得不可です。
- TCP/IPのブロードキャストやマルチキャストを使用するようなプロトコル([TFTPマルチキャストオプション](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2090.html)等)では、いずれのPCからも取得可能です。
- TCP/IPを使用しないプロトコル([NetBEUI](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/NetBEUI)上の古いSMB等)では、いずれのPCからも取得可能です。

色々繋がって複雑に見えますが、VLANによって論理的には、File serverと全てのPCは普通のHUBに繋がっていると見なせます。つまり、同じブロードキャストドメインに属しており、**互いにMACアドレスでの通信は可能です**。だからといって、IPアドレスでの通信が可能というわけではありません。

実際に①のPCが172.30.1.100にアクセスしようとした場合、どうなるかを見ましょう。①のPCでは、次のような設定になっているとします。

IPアドレス: 192.168.1.3
ネットマスク: 255.255.255.0
ゲートウェイ: 192.168.1.1

172.30.1.100も同じブロードキャストドメインにあるのでARP情報は取得できますので、PCのARPテーブルには他のPCのL3SWの他に172.30.1.100も存在しているかも知れません。しかし、それとは関係無く、172.30.1.100へ通信しようとするときは、L3SWの192.168.1.1のMACアドレス宛にパケットを飛ばします。これはどういうことかというと、ARPテーブルを参照する前に、まずはルーティングテーブルからどのインターフェースを使ってどのIPアドレスに飛ばすかを決定するからです。ルーティングテーブルはどのようになっているかを見てみましょう。(メトリックは省略)

| ネットワーク宛 | ネットマスク | ゲートウェイ | インターフェース |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0.0.0.0 | 0.0.0.0 | 192.168.1.1 | 192.168.1.3 |
| 192.168.1.0 | 255.255.255.0 | リンク上 | 192.168.1.3 |
| 192.168.1.3 | 255.255.255.255 | リンク上 | 192.168.1.3 |
| 192.168.1.255 | 255.255.255.255 | リンク上 | 192.168.1.3 |
| 224.0.0.0 | 240.0.0.0 | リンク上 | 192.168.1.3 |
| 255.255.255.255 | 255.255.255.255 | リンク上 | 192.168.1.3 |

OS表示内容に差異はあっても、通常はこのようになっています。テーブルで172.30.1.100がマッチするのは0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0のみであり、ゲートウェイは192.168.1.1になりますので、まずは192.168.1.1にパケットを飛ばそうとします。パケットの宛先IPは172.30.1.100のままですが、それを包むフレームの宛先MACアドレスは192.168.1.1のMACアドレスになり、それを実際のネットワーク上に流します。このフレームはスイッチングハブの機能によりL3SWにしか送られません。もし、HUBがただのリピータハブであればFile serverにも送られますが、**宛先MACアドレスが自分と異なるため破棄されます**。L3SWはフレームを受け取りパケットを取り出しますが、L3SWは172.30.1.100という勝手に付けられたIPアドレスは知らないため、自身のデフォルトゲートウェイに流すだけで、いずれはどこかで破棄されるでしょう。

ユニキャストでは無くブロードキャストやマルチキャストのみを使った場合はどうでしょう。ルーティングテーブルの224.0.0.0/240.0.0.0と255.255.255.255/255.255.255.255を見ればわかるように、ゲートウェイを経由せずに直接アクセスになります。マルチキャストはやや複雑ですが、ブロードキャストの場合はそのまま全てのPCにパケットが流れますので、通信は可能になるということです。

また、NetBEUIのようなTCP/IPを使用しないプロトコルであれば、先程の話はまるまる無視できます。

---

もし、ちゃんとセグメントを分けたいのであれば、L3SWで172.30.1.0/24系のVLANを作って、L2SWまでVLAN TAGで渡し、L2SWにそのVLANをUNTAGしたポートを作って、そこにFile serverを繋ぐべきです。裏技として、L3SWのVLAN3のインターフェースに172.30.1.1といった172.30.1.0/24系のゲートウェイアドレスを追加で設定するという手もありますが、一つのブロードキャストドメインに二つのネットワークセグメントが存在するという変則的な構成になるため、トラブルの基になる可能性が高く、推奨しません。

Comment: 詳しい解説ありがとうございます。自分の頭の中でふんわり理解していたことが、すっきりと整理できました。解決策も自分の想定どおりでした。